# How can I insert multiple IDs into different tables mysql?

Tags: mysql, join

Hi how can I insert the same ID as the account being created with this statement into a table which is called layouts using this mysql statement?

```
        $q = $dbc -> prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (email, password, salt, username, gender, loginIP, shrapnel, joined) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $q -> execute(array($_POST['email'], hash('sha512', 'jooosjdsakjdsn' .  $_POST['password'] . md5($random)), md5($random), $_POST['username'], $_POST['gender'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $random, date('Y-m-d : H:i:s')));
```

Is it possible with a join? The ID is an auto increment field in the table accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in another query immediately afterwards.

Comment: Worked awesome, and this is a fully supported mysql function??

Comment: It's in MySQL docs at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

you will have to add some sql to your script like  this
insert into layouts(accountsid,.......) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), ....).

Note: if the accounts table also has an identity column and you insert into it multiple times than you have to keep the LAST_INSERT_ID() for the master table into a separate variable otherwise starting with the second insert into the accounts table the LAST_INSERT_ID() function will return the IDs of the accounts table